# APNS Apple Push Service Notification not recieving

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have used the code for APNS Apple Push Service Notification The message is sending from my server but it is not receiving to the device. Check the URL below:

https://indiegirlworld.com/app/license_iphone/sample_push.php

Below is the messages I have obtained from the above link:

> Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:22:20 +0200 ApnsPHP[315874]: INFO: Trying
>   ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:22:21
>   +0200 ApnsPHP[315874]: INFO: Connected to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195. Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:22:21
>   +0200 ApnsPHP[315874]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue. Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:22:21 +0200
>   ApnsPHP[315874]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier:
>   Message-Badge-3] (1/3): 154 bytes. Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:22:21 +0200
>   ApnsPHP[315874]: INFO: Disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked in settings that Push notification are set to "ON"?

And another thing push notification can only received in Real devices not in Simulators.

You can send push notification from simulator (Because it is just a web service call.).

-- UPDATE --

The below code that requests for notifications.

Write in appDelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        NSLog(@"Requesting permission for push notifications..."); // iOS 8
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Registering device for push notifications..."); // iOS 7 and earlier
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }
```

Update below methods in you appDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    // Store DeviceToken some way like in NSUserDefault (if needed to pass device token)
    // Write alert for success to register for push
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error { 
    // Write alert for failed to register for push
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // Write alert code that shows you have successfully received alert
    // after that maintain your push
}
```

Comment: I have checked all these things Push notification are set to "ON" and checked in real device. But still iam not recieving the notification can you please with the above URL   https://indiegirlworld.com/app/license_iphone/sample_push.php

Comment: I also checked the device token on http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/ This sending and recieving notification on device

Comment: then now have to check all the codes you implemented. because push in not a big deal but first time this is very typical to implement..

Comment: I have taken the code from  https://github.com/immobiliare/ApnsPHP and executed it, but there is no error showing

Comment: do you have written php code that sends push or you are using readymade push services provided by other communities like parse.com or other..

Comment: look at updated code this may give you hint if you are fail to register for push.